# Recurrence relations for a substring that contains 0000 and for partioning an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

Having trouble with these two questions:

> Let $S_n$ be the number of bitstrings of length $n$ that contain the substring $0000$. Which of
>   the following is true?
>
> (a) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3} + S_{n-4}$
>   **(b) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3} + S_{n-4} + 2^{n-4}$**
>   (c) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3}$
>   (d) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3} + S_{n-4} + 2^{n-4}$

**The answer is (b).**

I accounted for the bitstrings that begin with:
$1 \rightarrow (S_{n-1})$,
$01 \rightarrow (S_{n-2})$,
$001 \rightarrow (S_{n-3})$,
$0001 \rightarrow (S_{n-4}),$ and,
$0000  \rightarrow (2^{n-4})$
This gives $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3} + S_{n-4} + 2^{n-4}$
Is my logic correct?

**How can I do this if I wanted to count bitstrings that *do not* contain $0000$ and then subtract those from all $2^n$ bitstrings to arrive at the same recurrence relation?**

---

Next question (this one I am not sure how to do):

> Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer and let $S_n$ be the number of ways in which $n$ can be written as a sum of 1s and 2s, such that:
>
> - the order in which the 1s and 2s occur in the sum matters, and
> - it is not allowed to have two consecutive 2s.
>
> For example, if $n = 7$, then both,
>   $7 = 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1$ and $7 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1$ are allowed, whereas $7 = 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1$ is not allowed.
>
> Which of the following is true?
>
> (a) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2}$
>   **(b) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-3}$**
>   (c) $S_n = S_{n-2} + S_{n-3}$
>   (d) $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3}$

**The answer is (b).**

Why is this true? I can't wrap my head around it. If all possibile sequences must start with $1$ and $21$ this should be **(a)** shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), you have 2 cases. a) the "partition" starts with a 1, and b) the partition starts with a 2.

a) This is just 1+(partition of n-1), and since here, the partition of n-1 used uniquely determines your partition of n, there are $S_{n-1}$ of these.

b) Since you start with 2, the next thing to be summed must be a 1. So your partition is 2+1+(partition of n-$\underbrace{3}_{=2+1}$). This is uniquely determined by the partition of n-3 that you use, so there are $S_{n-3}$ of these.

Combining cases a) and b) gives you $S_n=S_{n-1}+S_{n-3}$.

Comment: If we have $n = 3$ then the two possibilities would be $1 + 2 = 3$ and $2 + 1 = 3$. For $2+1 = 3$ we can use case b), but for $1 + 2 = 3$, we can apply case a) since it starts with a $1$, but then which case does the $2$ in $1 + 2$ follow? It can't follow case b) because case b) says that it must start with $2 + 1$ and if it only started with $2$ then that wouldn't be sufficient since it creates the possibility for consecutive $2$'s. Thank you though, this makes sense now because I forgot to consider the fact that the numbers have to add up to n - I thought the sequence had a length of n.

Comment: The recurrence is only defined for n>2 (otherwise, n-3 is a negative number)

Comment: So n=1, n=2, n=3 are base cases, then everything after n=3 can follow these cases without faulting on the last few numbers such as above? Ie. n = 4 would be 2+1+1 or 1+2+1 which is valid, and every n after that would never run into this issue.